# jhipster custom tables remain empty in production

Tags: java, database, jhipster, liquibase, production

For testing purposes I created csv files for uploading test data which works fine in development. In production however the tables for the custom entities remain empty. Any clues what the issue could be? Haven't found any hints so far; also I created another jhipster application for which the data is also created in production, but I couldn't find any differences so far ...

Comment: Have you checked that your Liquibase migrations don't use conditions on dbms or contexts?

Comment: I believe I have: application-dev shows "liquibase: contexts: dev", application-prod "liquibase: contexts: prod" but no context or preconditions attributes ... it seems to be the same in both applications, just that for one it's not working

Comment: finally located the problem: I have a column of type="bit". In dev I am using H2 and valueBoolean="true" works, for PostgreSQL in prod it doesn't. I was looking for a proper syntax to insert the data, no success so far ...